# Triangular numbers and powers

Tags: number-theory

I've noticed that the graphs of $y = \log_{a}\left(x^2 + x + a\right)$ passes through the following lattice points:

For $a = 2$:

- $\left(0, 1\right)$
- $\left(1, 2\right)$
- $\left(2, 3\right)$
- $\left(5, 5\right)$
- $\left(90, 13\right)$

For $a = 3$:

- $\left(0, 1\right)$
- $\left(2, 2\right)$
- $\left(15, 5\right)$

That's all I've got.

For $a \ge 4$, the only solution I've found is $x = a - 1$.

What are the next highest ***integer*** solutions for $a = 2$? For $a = 3$? For any arbitrary integer $a > 1$ in general?

Comment: Do you mean integers

Comment: we should expect only a finite number of $x$ values that work for any fixed $a.$ Things change if we add another variable you may get something: we can solve $x^2 + 3 y^2 = 7^k,$ for all $k \geq 1,$ with neither $x$ nor $y$ divisible by $7.$  Similar for $x^2 + xy + 2 y^2 = 2^k,$ with $x,y$ odd.

Comment: @Will Jagy: It seems to me that it is not obvious at all that "only a finite number of $(x,y)$ works for any fixed $a$. Look at the example $5^y-5=x^2+x$: for all $N>0$ you have a unique pair $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation. But $x-y$ is increasing with $N$ and not bounded, so...... Regards.

Comment: @Will Jagy: satisfying the equation is LHS=RHS=N

Comment: @Piquito not obvious. See http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=419063&tstart=0  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation

Comment: I guess it is a proof but a priori I repeat, it is not obvious at all. Your proof i will read tomorrow would say in other words that that in the infinity of (x,y) to consider not both are integer after a certain number.Thank you.